# Can a function with a const-reference as its parameter change the underlying object?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, parameter-passing

A const reference to a non-const variable can be cast to a non-const reference and then the underlying object can be modified through the reference.
Does it also hold for const-references in function declarations?

Namely, in the following code, is func() allowed to change 'a' provided 'a' is not originally const?
Or would this lead to undefined behaviour?

```
void func(const int& arg);

int main()
{
   int a = 5; //non-const
   func(a);
   std::cout << a; //Can func modify 'a' through a const-cast and thus output ≠5?
}
```

I am asking this since this would prevent the compiler from doing an optimization as it is forced to look the value of 'a' up again after func is evaluated; especially if the definition of func is in another translation unit.

Comment: It can *attempt* to do it. But it's usually not a good idea. That breaks the contract that the users of the function expected. And what if an actual constant object is passed, something which really isn't allowed to be modified?

Comment: So the big question for you is: Why do you need to do this? Is this question just plain curiosity? If so, then that's fine, but please [edit] your question to tell us. And if there's some other, underlying and actual problem behind your question, then please ask about that directly instead of making this an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) type question.

Comment: I am asking out of curiosity, I edited the question. This would prevent the compiler from doing an optimization; it is forced to look the value of 'a' up again after func is evaluated.

Comment: Of course. Since the original variable is not const, you can `const_cast` the const away and modify it w/o UB. Since it's legal code the optimizer should not assume the function will not change it. To be certain it isn't changed, just pass by value.

Comment: Interestingly. Why this language design was chosen would be another question.

Comment: @FranzFerdinand this is meant for a complex case. Passing a fundamental type by const reference doesn't make sense most of the time - a reference may br "bigger" or costier than an `int`. Passing a class object by `const` reference changes cv-modifiers used for name lookup when function would operate with classs. E.g. it would call const-specified version of overloaded member function. And even if no `const_cast` was done, the class could have `mutable` members which may change.

Comment: Const reference also can be bound to a temporal value which would not be copied to target location.

Comment: Perhaps defining the variable using the `volatile` [qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) instead? Though that could prevent other optimizations that you actually want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it can.

Calling `func` will make a reference which has an "unnecessary" `const`:

> A pointer or reference to a cv-qualified type need not actually point or refer to a cv-qualified object, but it is treated as if it does; [...]

- [[dcl.type.cv] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#3)

`func` can remove this "unnecessary" `const` with `const_cast`:

```cpp
void func(const int& arg)
{
    int& evil = const_cast<int&>(arg); // OK so far
    evil = 123; // undefined behavior only if arg refers to a const object
}
```

In this case, `func` *can* modify `a` through `evil`, because `a` is not a [const object](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.type.qualifier#def:object,const). However, if `a` was actually `const`, then this would be undefined behavior:

> Any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior.

- [[dcl.type.cv] p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4)

In general, if a function is given a reference or pointer, it can simply `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` that reference to any type it wants. However, if the type of object that is accessed is not *[similar](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#def:similar_types)* to that of the reference, this is undefined behavior in most cases. **The access may be undefined**, the `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` itself is fine.

### Impact on Compiler Optimizations

Consider the following simplified example:

```cpp
void func(const int&); // "Black box" function.
                       // The compiler cannot prove that func isn't modifying
                       // its arguments, so it must assume that this happens.
int main()
{
   int a = 5;
   func(a);  // func may be modifying a.
   return a; // The compiler cannot assume that this is 'return 5'.
}
```

With optimizations, clang outputs:

```
main:
        push    rax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], 5
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 4]
        call    func(int const&)@PLT
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/r781Kj9Me)*

This code does suffer from the fact that `func` can modify `a`.

- `mov dword ptr [rsp + 4], 5` stores `a` on the stack
- `mov eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]` loads `a` from the stack after `func` was called

If you write `const int a = 5;` instead, the assembly ends with `mov eax, 5`, and `a` is not spilled onto the stack, because it cannot be modified by `func`. This is more efficient.